# Build a dependency if not found in the system

Tags: cmake

I need to use LibSoundIO in my project, but it's not always in the official repos.

Right now I use a FindSoundIO.cmake :

```
find_path(SOUNDIO_INCLUDE_DIR soundio/soundio.h
    HINTS $ENV{SOUNDIO_ROOT}/include)

find_library(SOUNDIO_LIBRARY
    NAMES soundio
    HINTS $ENV{SOUNDIO_ROOT}/lib)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(SOUNDIO DEFAULT_MSG SOUNDIO_LIBRARY SOUNDIO_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(SOUNDIO_LIBRARY SOUNDIO_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

The HINTS are use for Windows builds (the extern libs are in an extern/ directory).
For Linux, WHEN cmake does not find the libraries in /usr/lib, how can I do to build SoundIO and mark it as an include+link dependency ? (it's using cmake itself).
The best would be not to bloat my CMakeLists.txt of course ;)
Thanks !

Comment: You may use `find_package(SoundIO QUIET)` first. If it fails (variable *SoundIO_FOUND* is false-evaluated), then build the library by yourself and set *SOUNDIO_INCLUDE_DIR* and *SOUNDIO_LIBRARY* correspondingly. Actually, there are many approaches to conditionally build 3d-party library, just choose one which is suitable for you and begin coding.

Comment: Thanks, that's an idea. I'll try to set this up.